# MySql DB column primary key generation using ADF

Tags: mysql, oracle-adf

I am using jdev 11.1.2.4 and MySql db.

How can we generate primary key of MySql db column using groovy/declaratively or even programmatically?

below link is to acheive the same programmtically in 12c

http://www.java-n-me.com/2013/11/using-mysql-autoincrement-pk-column-in.html

the issue with this approach is that after commit, the generated key is not displayed on the page.

thanks

Comment: Why would you generate PK yourself?

Comment: My requirement is get the latest id from the database and display it on the page. as there will be multiple users who can access this page at the same time, so this id should be unique to all of them.

Comment: Ok, judging from what you said - MySQL would generate a non-unique primary keys and it wouldn't provide you with the latest one generated, so you decided it's better you control atomicity and consistency from your application which is impossible by definition? I don't understand what's exactly wrong with `auto_increment` and `LAST_INSERT_ID();` which were made for what you described. Are you aware of how MySQL works at all or not? If not, it's better to ask if it provides such facilities rather than assuming it doesn't.

Comment: I am new to MySql/Web Development with little knowledge about these functions. Please can you advise how can I achieve my task using these?

Comment: Define primary key as `auto_increment` when creating your table, there are numerous examples available. After you're done with inserting into that table, call MySQL's `LAST_INSERT_ID();` function with `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as last_id;`. I'm sure ADF has methods for doing the latter.

Comment: if multiple users adding into this table at the same time, will they all get different value using Last_insert_id()?